# Delayed block 19372460 returned wrong timestamp and set of tx through eth_getBlockReceipts on Erigon Archive node

Tags: erigon

I'm indexing blocks / transactions **as they come in**.
To that end I'm using calls to `eth_getBlockReceipts`.

I'm seeing the weird issue that when I was indexing block 19372460 it responded with:

- timestamp: 2024-03-06T00:09:59Z
- 407 transactions

This appears to be incorrect when looking at [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/block/19372460). And indeed, when querying the block (`eth_getBlockByNumber`) and it's tx (`eth_getBlockReceipts`) **now** (so a couple of hours after it was produced, instead of when the block was just produced), I'm getting the correct results (as cross-checked with etherscan at least):

- timestamp: 2024-03-06T00:10:11Z
- 162 tx

This gives quite a few problems, since a lot of these tx were included in the next block, thus my indexer is processing these tx twice.

Now I could create some code to check for duplicate tx, but I feel this is just patching a much deeper issue.

Therefore, I like to know: **why does this happen?** Is it likely a bug in Erigon, or are there known conditions under which this can occur?

To be clear, I'm seeing duplicate tx a couple of times a day and this always involves a block that was delayed. (Another one is https://etherscan.io/block/19373565 which my node first saw come in at 2024-03-06T03:52:23Z instead of 2024-03-06T03:52:35Z, again with faulty 'ghost' tx.

I was thinking of a reorg at first, but seeing this happens a couple of times a day at least and afaik no reorg has happened yet on Ethereum mainnet since POS (and is [unlikely to ever happen since POS](https://www.paradigm.xyz/2021/07/ethereum-reorgs-after-the-merge)) , I highly doubt this is the issue.

Anyone?